# Python prime checker faulty with 25?

Tags: python

So I'm relatively new to Python and trying to define a function which will check to see if a number is prime or not. The code is as follows:

```
def prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(3, int((x**0.5)+1)):
            if x % i == 0:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

This seems to work for most values however it fails on certain values such as 25, can anyone help to explain to me why? Thanks!

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test.

Comment: There's more efficient algorithms, for sure, but the general gist is not *that* wrong, I think.

Comment: @RohitJ: He does attempt to do that, with `int(x**0.5)+1)`.

Comment: @RohitJ: Although, he only need to check *primes* not all natural numbers.

Comment: @user667648 this algorithm is good enough.  Generating a large list of primes often ends up wasting more runtime than just doing this, especially if this is just an exercise to learn Python.

Comment: @SimonT: His algorithm is good enough. I am just point it out, for example, in the Prime Project Euler problem, checking only primes actually helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

`return` leaves your function once it is reached. Let's look at the case of `25`.

- Is `x<2` no, so continue.
- Is it `x==2` no, so continue.
- Is `x` divisible by `i(=3)`? No, so go to the `else` clause, `return True` leave the function.

See the issue?

To put it another way, for **sufficiently large** `x`, your function is equivalent to:

```
def prime_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    else:
        if x % 3 == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the

```
else:
```

clause, the first `i` it checks will make it return true.

Instead, write

```
else:
    for i in range(3, int((x**0.5)+1)):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

EDIT:
And as @mata points out, you actually need to start at 2, so it should be `for i in range(2, int((x**0.5)+1)):`

Comment: Maybe a good idea, since the guy is new to Python, to enforce that Python is indentation *sensative*. :)

Comment: The range needs to start at 2, not at 3. Otherwise 4, 6, 8, ... would be considered prime.

Comment: @mata question is why it gives wrong answer for 25 :) but you're right of course. Updated.